# System.out.println issue

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Factors {
        public static void main (String [] args){
            System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factors for: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = keyboard.nextInt();
            ArrayList<Integer> Factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++){
                if(input % i == 0){
                    if(Factors.contains(i)){
                        break;
                    }
                    Factors.add(i);
                    Factors.add(input / i);
                    System.out.println("Factors are: " + i + " and " + input / i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The second if statement is simply so it doesn't repeat factors. But I want it to print "Enter a number to find the factors for: and then read a user input on the same line. If I use println, then it goes to the next line. If I use print, then it won't ask "Enter a number to find the factors for: until I give an input. How can I fix this and why does it happen?

Comment: Hi, `System.out.print` should print the text on the same line. If not, perhaps try `System.out.flush()` after each `print`.

Comment: That has not worked

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: Netbeans Apache

Comment: What if you add an empty println before the print?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue using the standard Netbeans console.  Please let us know if you're directing the standard input and output streams elsewhere.